# Inserters for STL stack and priority_queue

Tags: c++, stl, containers, priority-queue, inserter

`std::vector`, `std::list` and `std::deque` have `std::back_inserter`, and `std::set` has `std::inserter`.

For `std::stack` and `std::priority_queue` I would assume the equivalent inserter would be a `push()` but I can't seem to find the correct function to call.

My intent is to be able to use the following function with the correct insert iterator:

```
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <iterator>

template<typename outiter>
void foo(outiter oitr)
{
   static const std::string s1 ("abcdefghji");
   static const std::string s2 ("1234567890");
   *oitr++ = s1;
   *oitr++ = s2;
}

int main()
{
   std::priority_queue<std::string> spq;
   std::stack<std::string> stk;

   foo(std::inserter(spq));
   foo(std::inserter(stk));

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The other alternative (simpler) is just to use the underlying data structure (`std::stack` is usually implemented using `std::deque`) and accept that you have to use e.g. `push_back()` instead of `push()`. Saves having to code your own iterator, and doesn't particularly affect the clarity of the code. `std::stack` isn't your only choice for modelling the stack concept.

Answer (score 4):

You can always go your own way and implement an iterator yourself.  I haven't verified this code but it should work.  Emphasis on "I haven't verified."

```
template <class Container>
  class push_insert_iterator:
    public iterator<output_iterator_tag,void,void,void,void>
{
protected:
  Container* container;

public:
  typedef Container container_type;
  explicit push_insert_iterator(Container& x) : container(&x) {}
  push_insert_iterator<Container>& operator= (typename Container::const_reference value){
    container->push(value); return *this; }
  push_insert_iterator<Container>& operator* (){ return *this; }
  push_insert_iterator<Container>& operator++ (){ return *this; }
  push_insert_iterator<Container> operator++ (int){ return *this; }
};
```

I'd also add in the following function to help use it:

```
template<typename Container>
push_insert_iterator<Container> push_inserter(Container container){
    return push_insert_iterator<Container>(container);
}
```

Comment: So what you're saying is that there isn't a standard one such as std::back_inserter or std::inserter - in short your answer is pretty good and what i'm currently doing... just hoped that i had missed something in the stl - don't like rolling out my own when there already is something in the stl

Comment: @sonicoder not that I know of.  I only know front, back, and regular inserters besides the ones from ostream.  You might look at Boost but I believe even these will leave you wanting for what you need.

Comment: I think it should be: std::iterator<std::output_iterator_tag,void,void,void,void>

Comment: @sonicoder so you're right.  iterator only has 5 arguments.  I've also added in a helper function much akin to `back_inseter` or `front_inserter` functions.

Comment: @sonicoder let me know how it works.  I might want to use this myself in the future.

Comment: I wonder why such an iterator class template was not added to the standard. Are there issues that we do not see?