# std::copy for copying vector to priority_queue

Tags: c++, vector, stl, priority-queue

I am trying to copy a `std::vector` into `std::priority_queue` while the following two approaches are working.

```
vector<int> parts = { 8, 4, 6, 12, 57, 28};                          //source
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int>> minHeap;              //target
```

approach 1:

```
all_of(parts.begin(), parts.end(), [&minHeap](int& part){minHeap.push(part); return true;});
```

approach 2:

```
for(int& part: parts) minHeap.push(part);
```

However, I'd like to know if the same can be done by [`std::copy`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/)?

Comment: Why not use the constructor? `priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int>> minHeap(parts.begin(), parts.end());` ?

Comment: surprisingly I didn't think of the constructor. thanks for enlightening me.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115431/inserters-for-stl-stack-and-priority-queue

Comment: `std::all_of()` is not intended for this work - it is intended to check if a condition is true for all elements. It might work for you, but would be confusing for the readers. If you want an algorithm here, use `std::for_each()` - but it no better in this case than `for` loop.

Comment: @Eugene yeah I know it was a tweak.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can be done with `std::copy()`, but only if you write (or find) a custom [`OutputIterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/OutputIterator) that calls the queue's `push()` method when the iterator is written to. The standard library has no such iterator built-in for calling `push()` (but it has [`std::front_insert_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/front_insert_iterator) for `push_front()`, [`std::back_insert_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator) for `push_back()`, [`std::insert_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/insert_iterator) for `insert()`, etc).

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I'd like to do a little research on your approach of custom `OutputIterator`